# C# Httpclient content-length

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm curious as to why my HttpClient post request is returning a higher content-length than when I perform the same request manually?

Example -

via HttpClient using

```
var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

returns

```
 (Header data)
 ...
 Content-Length: 14500
 ...
```

but if I repeat the same request manualy, the content length is much lower

```
 Content-Length: 4854
```

Is this down to HttpClient? I'm also using proxies so not sure if that'll cause the increase but figured I would state that just incase.

Comment: Dunno, maybe the server isn't sending the same thing back the second time?  Your question doesn't contain enough information, all we can do is shrug and guess.

Comment: I've ran multiple requests manually & programmatically. Everytime manually content-length is 4 digits, everytime programmatically the content-length is 5 digits. Also yes I agree that my question doesn't necessarily contain enough information, but there really isn't much to it, other than I'm using HttpClient + Proxies..

Comment: What is the difference in the actual content returned?

Comment: try to inspect your http--content in both cases, sometimes CRLF are converted to LF, the char encoding changes..try to specify the charset in the Content-Type header and check if it solves your problem

Comment: I think @phuzi is on the right track. You seem to be focused on the length, when the real concern should be the content of the response. If you compare the content itself, what is different about them? Most likely there is something different in the requests being submitted, causing a different response. Also, how exactly are you 'repeating the request manually'?

Comment: @phuzi well atm I'm just receiving headers as you can see from "  HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead " and in terms of header value there is no difference, but content-length refers to the body content, so I guess I'll have accept the body-content and review it.

Comment: When you do it manually the useragent may have an "accept" header indicating it can consume compressed/gzipped data, HttpClient will not do this by default.

Comment: @AlexK. that's a great shout, thanks I didn't think of that so I'll look into it now & see if it makes a change :).

Comment: @AlexK. that was the solution I needed, thank you very much & thanks to everyone who also highlighted potential issues! appreciate your time guys.

Comment: You or @AlexK. should submit an answer for some rep.  I would do so, but I didn't come up with the solution, so it would be... unethical, I think.